# SQL JOINing on max value, even if it is 0

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, distinct

I have two tables that look roughly like this:

```
Airports
uniqueID | Name
0001     | Dallas


Runways
uniqueID | AirportID | Length
000101   | 0001      | 8000
```

I'm doing a join that looks like this:

```
SELECT Airports.Name, Runways.Length FROM Airports, Runways 
WHERE Airports.uniqueID==Runways.AirportID
```

Obviously, each runway has exactly one airport, and each airport has 1..n runways.

For an airport with multiple runways, this gives me several rows, one for each runway at that airport. 
I want a result set that contains ONLY the row for the longest runway, i.e. MAX(Length).
Sometimes, the Length is 0 for several runways in the database, because the source data is missing. In that case I only want one row with the Length = 0 obviously.

I've tried the approach laid out here: [Inner Join table with respect to a maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402025/inner-join-table-with-respect-to-a-maximum-value) but that's actually not helpful because that's like searching for the longest runway of all, not for the longest at one particular airport.

Comment: What criteria is used to determine the runway to return when several have length 0?  (the airportID smallest airportID?)

Comment: @xQbert It can be random. If they are stored in the DB with Length=0, I don't care. Just pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to simple to be what you want but it seems to meet all the cases you've described...

```
SELECT A.Name, Max(R.Length)
FROM Airports A
INNER JOIN Runways R
 on A.uniqueID=R.AirportID
Group by A.Name
```

This should give you the max runway for each airport.

If you need additional data elements then use the above as a inline view (Subquery within the joins) to limit the results sets to just those airports and their max runway.

Comment: Nope, that's it. If it seems "too simple" then that's because I haven't done any SQL since 2005 so I have forgotten even the simplest things.